# How to extract 95% confidence bounds from fit() result matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I fit a line to a data as follows:

```
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( lnN, lne );

ft = fittype( 'poly1' );

[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft );
```

where the `fitresult` var is:

```
>> fitresult

fitresult = 

     Linear model Poly1:
     fitresult(x) = p1*x + p2
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =     -0.1331  (-0.1437, -0.1226)
       p2 =      -2.625  (-2.699, -2.552)
```

But when I try to get the confidence bounds on `p1`, for instance, it only prints the average:

```
>> fitresult.p1

ans =

    -0.1331
```

How can I extract these bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
%create a string from the output of fit()
out = evalc('fitresult');

%crop out the relevant part of the string (by counting characters)
out = out(145:170);

%search between ( and , for the lower limit
p1_lower = str2num(out((strfind(out,'(')+1):(strfind(out,',')-1)));

%search between , and ) for the upper limit
p1_upper = str2num(out((strfind(out,',')+1):(strfind(out,')')-1)));
```

**EDIT** As per @alexforrence's suggestion, I checked what methods the `fitresults` object has. Therefore the following solution is MUCH simpler:

```
[intervals] = confint(fitresult);
```

This results in a 2 by 2 matrix, holding the upper and lower bounds for `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: There's a much, much easier way. Check under `methods(fitresult)`.